# Connection string to MySql Database

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I am trying to do an Sql bulk copy from a data table to MySQL database and I have this connection string in my App.config

```
    <add name="DatastoreDataContextConnectionString" connectionString=" Data         
    Source=localhost; User Id=root;Database=datastore;Persist Security Info=True"
    />
```

And this is my main code

```
string consString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatastoreDataContextConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
{
    using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
    {
        //Set the database table name
        sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.storedata";
        con.Open();
        sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(table);
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

But my con.Open() keeps giving me this error
       Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

I also tried creating a new data source (Shift + Alt + D) in my visual studio and I received the same error
Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Are you able to connect to this database by some client using the same credentials which you are providing in code?

Comment: Yes, i use these credentials when i code in php and they work fine @AlokGupta

Comment: Did you try Integrated Security = true? are you also providing password in the connection string but may be you have not mentioned here?

Comment: the only credential needed to log in is the username @AlokGupta

Comment: Please try Integrated Security = true

Comment: Tried that,But still giving the error @AlokGupta

Comment: the page can not be found @MarkW

Comment: can you try removing persist security info thing?

Answer (score 0):

please give port number in connection string..after local host port=XXXX;

Answer (score 0):

try to add providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" to your connectionstring.
Also i think you have to write the password to connect to your db in connectionsString so it would be like this:

```
<add name="DatastoreDataContextConnectionString" connectionString=" Data         
Source=localhost; User Id=root;Password=yourPassword;Database=datastore;Persist Security Info=True"
providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
/>
```